# Query for Extracting the Version info from Webpage

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

I am try to extract the version info from the webpage using php.

```
function catche(string $url)  {

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    $value1 = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $value1;
}

function getVersioninfofromwebpage($url) {
    $content = fetch($url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($content);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $result = $xpath->query("//span[contains(text(),'VMware Tools')]//following-sibling::ul//span[contains(text(),'Release Notes')]//following-sibling::ul//li[1]//a");

    $version = $result->item(0)->textContent;
    # expected version info is 11.0.6 

    $modversion = explode(".", $version);
    array_pop($modversion);
    $modversion = implode(".", $modversion);

    $version1 = str_replace('.', '', $version);


    $buildUrl = "https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tools/" . $modversion . "/rn/VMware-Tools-" . $version1 . "-Release-Notes.html"

    # expected url "https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tools/11.0/rn/VMware-Tools-1106-Release-Notes.html"
    $content = fetch($url);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($content);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);


    $result = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@id, 'content')]/table");

    $header = $result->item(0)->textContent;

    $rx = preg_match("((\d+))", $header, $matches);

    $build = $matches[1];

    return "$version" . "." . "$build" ;

}
$url = "https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tools/index.html";
$val = getVersioninfofromwebpage($url);
echo $val;
```

It seems my queries went wrong i am not getting any info and getting the errors.
can any one help me to get the version info.
expected result is : 11.0.6.15940789

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error: is it `$version`, `$buildUrl`, `$build`?

Comment: $version is not giving anything. i am getting the error. say PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'textContent' of non-object in /workspace/Main.php.  at $version = $result->item(0)->textContent;

Comment: The content that you are targeting is delivered by js and is not available through a standard curl technique.  I fed your sample url into https://reqbin.com/curl then manually searched through the returned source code in my IDE and found that the left panel content was not incorporated.